# DataStage is getting this error "ORA-02429: Cannot drop index used for enforcement of unique/primary key, but it worked fine before"

Tags: database, oracle, indexing, key, datastage

I have a big problem. I was executing my DataStage jobs as always, which was working fine, but unexpectedly I've got an error in all my jobs that have an Oracle Stage destination.

Error is like this:

```
 ORA-02429: Cannot drop index used for enforcement of unique/primary key
```

No matter what table or what db, every job is having that error. We tried restarting DataStage Engine/Service Tier, Oracle db, but nothing is working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648681/enforcement-of-unique-primary-key-drop-index

Comment: @VBokšić that's not the problem. As I said, my jobs were workinf fine, Tables has no key constraints

Comment: hmmm and you said : "but unexpectly I've get a error in all my jobs" so not working fine ?

Comment: @VBokšić I have multiple jobs that worked fine, if running again: error. Nobodys did something to the tables. That's why I added DataStage to my problem, because maybe its a problem related to a patch or config file corrupted

Comment: If you have audit enabled then try to query `dba_audit_trail`. Maybe you'll find when constraint appeared

Answer (score 0):

Things usually don't happen *just because*. Here's what might have happened.

First, situation you had until recently: there's an index you can drop:

```
SQL> create table test (id number);

Table created.

SQL> create index i1 on test (id);

Index created.

SQL> drop index i1;

Index dropped.
```

---

Let's create it again:

```
SQL> create index i1 on test (id);

Index created.
```

Meanwhile, someone decided to create primary key on the indexed column (index already exists so primary key will use it; if it didn't exist, `alter table` would create it):

```
SQL> alter table test add constraint pk_test primary key (id);

Table altered.
```

This is what is happening now when you're trying to drop that index:

```
SQL> drop index i1;
drop index i1
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02429: cannot drop index used for enforcement of unique/primary key


SQL>
```

Which means: drop the primary key first:

```
SQL> alter table test drop constraint pk_test;

Table altered.

SQL> drop index i1;

Index dropped.

SQL>
```

As you have a job the does that, things might not be that simple any more. You can create a *procedure* which will query metadata and *dynamically* do that, but ... first investigate what happened between "it was working" and "it doesn't work any more".

Comment: I have multiple jobs that worked fine, if running again: error. Nobodys did something to the tables. That's why I added DataStage to my problem, because maybe its a problem related to a patch or config file corrupted

Comment: That's what I meant by my last sentence. Things don't "break" by themselves. Someone did something; find who it was.